# Simple.Data nested join retrieval

Tags: simple.data

I'm using Simple.Data but can't seem to get it to fully populate my related objects from a single query. I've checked some of the other questions on StackOverflow but nothing has so far been successful.

I have objects:

```
public class ProductVersion
{
    public int VersionId { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public int VariantId { get; set; }
    public int MarketId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FileDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
    public int RevisionId { get; set; }
    public Model Model { get; set; }
    public Variant Variant { get; set; }
    public Market Market { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
    public int VariantId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Market
{
    public int MarketId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

( ProductVersion has a Model, Variant and Market, and Market has a Language )

Then, I'm attempting to retrieve a single instance of ProductVersion using:

```
ProductVersion instance = db
    .ProductVersion
    .With(db.ProductVersion.Model)
    .With(db.ProductVersion.Variant)
    .With(db.ProductVersion.Market)
    .With(db.ProductVersion.Market.Language)
    .Get(1);
    ;
```

I get an instance of ProductCatalogVersion returned, with Model, Variant, and Market properties populated but Market.Language is null. I can see the correct joins being issued in the SQL and the Language table is being read I just can't get it to populate the Language property of Market.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple.Data doesn't support the hydrating of grandchild tables into a POCO. Thus the Language table doesn't work while the others do. I believe that this feature is planned for support in the v2 timeline but when exactly it will be implemented is up in the air.

Comment: Many thanks Hmobius.
That's a shame, especially as it's issuing the correct SQL, but it doesn't leave me dead in the water and I can workaround for now. Simple.Data has so many other positives going for it that I'll continue to use it and wait for v2.